# Python 3.7: Using regex on a string with whitespace in the beginning

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

I have lines in a text file that I need to parse with regular expressions and assign numbers to variables. Here is an example of what the lines look like

```
      1   35 A K              0   0  182
```

So there is whitespace at the beginning of the string, and whenever I use this website (https://pythex.org/) it does not seem to match anything when I use the regular expression

```
^s+\d+\s+\d+\s\w\s\w\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d
```

How can I use regular expressions to assign 182 to a variable?

Comment: You're missing a backslash on the first `s+`. Try changing it to `^\s+\d+\s+\d+\s\w\s\w\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex.

```
^\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)
```

You can put the last number in a group which you can capture in your code.

Following is a test python script.

```
import re

regex = r"^\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)"

test_str = "      1   35 A K              0   0  182"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Output:

```
Match 1 was found at 0-40:       1   35 A K              0   0  182
Group 1 found at 37-40: 182
```